# Changing data resolution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a set o data (stored in 2D numpy arrays) representing simulations for a same problem. However, each simulation comes from a different model, which results in different resolutions for each of them. For example, these are some of the simulations' sizes:

1. 1159 x 1367
2. 144 x 157
3. 72 x 82
4. 446 x 500
5. 135 x 151

What I'd like to do is to convert them all to the same resolution, for instance, 144 x 157. I believe I have to perform an interpolation, however, I'm not sure which method to use in Python.

I've been reading about these:

1. [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)
2. [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html)
3. [scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html)
4. [scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html)

The (3) and (4) seems to fit best the problem, however, I'm unsure about how to make them return a new gridded (2D) data, with an specified resolution.

Comment: Are all of your data cover the same range of coordinates?  In other words, are all of the measurements between (for instance) 0 to 3 in x, and 0 to 10 in y?

Comment: Yes, they all cover the same region, but in different resolutions.

Comment: These being simulations are thee data noise-free?

Comment: They are smoothed during the last step of simulation.

Comment: I was just asking because if noise is isgnificant you may want consider using not interpolation but some kind of averaging on the oversampled bits of the data.

Comment: But I have the two cases, data with higher resolution than the desired one, and data with lower resolution than the desired. I might have to use two approaches, @PaulPanzer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you shouldn't interpolate the undersampled data. Just trying to make your life even more complicated ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that I could solve it using [scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2DY7.png):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

def regrid(data, out_x, out_y):
    m = max(data.shape[0], data.shape[1])
    y = np.linspace(0, 1.0/m, data.shape[0])
    x = np.linspace(0, 1.0/m, data.shape[1])
    interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((y, x), data)

    yv, xv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1.0/m, out_y), np.linspace(0, 1.0/m, out_x))

    return interpolating_function((xv, yv))
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Why do you import pylab in your example?